# Couldn't find my Api-key in my firebase console for my flutter project sign-up authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, api-key, web-setup-project

I'm new to flutter and trying to implement sign-up authentication in flutter using Firebase. But the problem is that when i learned about authentication, they provided a post method url which must accept API-KEY in it. 
Now, i dont know where does my API-KEY exists.

`http.post(https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API-KEY]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find it in Project Settings under the General tab.

[image]

[image]

If you add a web app, it's also the first parameter in the config.

[image]